# import header/footer in Velocity

Tags: java, coldfusion, velocity

I am trying to use what I have in  to import a header/footer URL/content to my web pages in a velocity template. Do we have such thing in velocity?

**I mean importing the header/footer from a web URL which is not a velocity file/template.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Given the coldfusion tag, the cfhttp tag might help.

Answer (score 0):

A step by step header and footer including is given in this tutorial:[How to configure Apache Velocity template engine](http://www.giuseppeurso.eu/en/how-to-configure-apache-velocity-template-engine/)

### WebContent/WEB-INF/template/layout.vm

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/my.css" media="all" type="text/css">  
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center" >
    <table class="tabellaLayout" >
        <tr >
            <td ><div align="center" >#parse("/template/header.vm")</div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td ><div align="center">$screen_content</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td ><div align="center">#parse("/template/footer.vm")</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### WebContent/WEB-INF/template/header.vm

```
<table >
    <tr >
        <td >MY HEADER</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### WebContent/WEB-INF/template/footer.vm

```
<table >
    <tr >
        <td > MY FOOTER</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I meant...I mean importing the header/footer from a web URL which is not a velocity file/template.